# Bottom of text cut off in detailTextLabel

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `tableView` with the bottom of low hanging characters (g, p, q, etc) in `detailTextView` being cut off. Changing the font size and cell height doesn't seem to fix the problem. I can't set values of the cells labels so I am out of ideas. Any help?

Here is a pic of an example.

[image]
EDIT: I found that using fontawesome is what is causing this. I have no idea why fontawesome is doing this but removing this line of code in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` removes the problem

```
cell.detailTextLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "FontAwesome", size: 16)
```

Now I have no idea why changing the font is causing this issue, nor how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add these two lines of code to your `UITableView` set up:

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension // 1
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50 // 2
```

// 1 This tells the `UITableView` that its cells should be as height as their content

// 2 This is needed by the `UITableView` to calculate its scroll bar height and position. This value does not have to be 100% correct, an estimation on your average cell height is enough.

Comment: This doesn't do anything for me. Changing where I put the code doesn't seem to help either.

Comment: Can you add the code where you dequeue the cell and configure it to your question?